# How to search from the added student in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    char name[20];
    char ID[20];
    int age;
    char course[20];
    int yrlvl;
};

struct student students;

int main() {
    Main_Menu();
    return 0;
}

void Main_Menu() {
    int choice;
    while (1) {
        printf("1. Add Student\n");
        printf("2. Edit Student Information\n");
        printf("3. View all Records\n");
        printf("4. Search Student\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
          case 1:
            add_student();
            break;
          case 2:
            //mod_student();
            break;
          case 3:
            break;
          case 4:
            search_student();
            break;
          case 5:
            exit(0);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

void add_student() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("record.txt", "ab+");
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nStudent Name: ");
    gets(students.name);
    printf("\nStudent ID: ");
    scanf("%s", students.ID);
    printf("\nCourse: ");
    scanf("%s", students.course);
    printf("\nYear Level: ");
    scanf("%d", &students.yrlvl);
    printf("\nAge:");
    scanf("%d", &students.age);
    fclose(fp);
    return;
}

void search_student() {
    char s_id[15];
    int isFound = 0;
    printf("Enter Student ID to Search: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(s_id);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("record.txt", "r");
    while (fread(&students, sizeof(students), 1, fp) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(s_id, students.ID) == 0) {
            isFound = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isFound == 1) {
        printf("\nThe record is Found");
        printf("\nStudent ID: %s",students.ID);
        printf("\nStudent Name: %s",students.name);
        printf("\nCourse: %s",students.course);
        printf("\nYear Level:%d ",students.yrlvl);
        printf("\nAge: %d\t",students.age);
    } else {
        printf("Sorry, No record found\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return;
}
```

In `void search_student()`, The called value is not printing.
For example  the user inputs:

```
Student Name: Juan
Student Id: 1
Course: IT
Year level: 1
Age: 15
```

(Then it will go back to the main menu)
If the user picks the search student and then enters the student id: `1`, it should print the name, course, year level, and age. But my code is not working. My code prints `Sorry, No record found`. The expected output if the user enters again the student id:1,

```
The record is Found
Student ID: 1
Student Name: Juan
Course: IT
Year level: 1
Age: 15
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEArU.png)

Comment: In `add_student` `fflush(stdin);` flushing an input stream causes undefined behaviour. Also, in that function what's the purpose of that file `FILE*fp=...` to start withl? You don't write to it at all. That might be your main issue.

Comment: Some rules for hunting bugs: Your title asks about searching. You need to make sure there is something to search. You must check that the file holds the content you expect. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to start searching. If you do that, you will know that your problem is the part where the input should go into the file. With that knowledge (or even right from the start), run your program in a debugger and step through the relevant code. In each line (`add_student`) check if it does what you think it should do. Discuss it with your [Rubber duck](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/)!

Comment: Don't show pictures of text. Show text as properly formatted text. Your output is text.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `gets()` is an obsolete function: do not use it.
- `gets_s()` is a non portable function with tricky semantics: do not use it.
- instead, you could use `scanf()` to read strings and numbers as long as you pass the size of the destination arrays and the appropriate conversion format.
- always test the return value of `scanf()`.
- do not use `fflush(stdin)` it has undefined behavior. If you want to discard the rest of the previous input line use this:

  ```
   int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
       continue;
  ```
- `add_student` does not append the new `student` structure to the file **record.txt**
- in `search_student()`, you should open the file **record.txt** in binary more, especially on legacy systems that still convert line endings.
- it is a bad idea to store student data in binary format: less portable and more difficult to debug. Furthermore, naming this binary file **record.txt** is misleading.
- it is customary in C to output the newlines (`'\n'`) at the end of each line instead of at the beginning.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student {
    char name[20];
    char ID[20];
    int age;
    char course[20];
    int year_level;
};

int main_menu(void);
int add_student(void);
int view_students(void);
int search_student(void);

int main() {
    return main_menu();
}

int main_menu(void) {
    for (;;) {
        int choice;
        printf("1. Add Student\n"
               "2. Edit Student Information\n"
               "3. View all Records\n"
               "4. Search Student\n"
               "5. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &choice) != 1)
            return 0;
        printf("\n");
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            add_student();
            break;
        case 2:
            //mod_student();
            break;
        case 3:
            view_students();
            break;
        case 4:
            search_student();
            break;
        case 5:
            return 0;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

int add_student(void) {
    struct student students;

    printf("Student Name: ");
    if (scanf(" %19[^\n]", students.name) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("  Student ID: ");
    if (scanf(" %19[^\n]", students.ID) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("      Course: ");
    if (scanf(" %19[^\n]", students.course) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("  Year Level: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &students.year_level) != 1)
        return -1;
    printf("         Age: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &students.age) != 1)
        return -1;

    FILE *fp = fopen("record.txt", "a");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open record.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    fprintf(fp, "%s,%s,%d,%s,%d\n",
            students.name, students.ID, students.age,
            students.course, students.year_level);
    printf("Record added\n");
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

void print_student(struct student *sp) {
    printf("Student ID: %s\n", sp->ID);
    printf("Student Name: %s\n", sp->name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", sp->age);
    printf("Course: %s\n", sp->course);
    printf("Year Level:%d\n ", sp->year_level);
}

int view_students(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("record.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open record.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    char buf[200];
    struct student students;
    int recno = 1;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        if (sscanf(buf, "%19[^,],%19[^,],%d,%19[^,],%d",
                   students.name, students.ID, &students.age,
                   students.course, &students.year_level) == 5)
        {
            printf("Record %d:\n", recno++);
            print_student(&students);
            printf("\n");
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid record: %s", buf);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

int search_student(void) {
    char s_id[20];

    printf("Enter Student ID to Search: ");
    if (scanf(" %19[^\n]", s_id) != 1)
        return -1;

    FILE *fp = fopen("record.txt", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open record.txt: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    char buf[200];
    struct student students;
    int isFound = 0;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        if (sscanf(buf, "%19[^,],%19[^,],%d,%19[^,],%d",
                   students.name, students.ID, &students.age,
                   students.course, &students.year_level) == 5)
        {
            if (strcmp(s_id, students.ID) == 0) {
                isFound = 1;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid record: %s", buf);
        }
    }
    if (isFound == 1) {
        printf("The record is found:\n");
        print_student(&students);
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Sorry, No record found\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return isFound;
}
```